# How to enforce a Tomcat web application to read/write/delete files only in the specified directories

Tags: java, tomcat

I need to install a web application on a Tomcat server.  The web application needs to read and write files on the production server machine.  However, for security concerns, I want to create some directories on the product server machine and enforce the web application to read and write files in the directories.

It seems that I can do it through the Tomcat security policy file.  Assume that I create two directories: d:\data1 and d:\data2.

Can anyone help by showing me the required permissions?

Comment: You can try `chroot` if you on linux

Comment: Thanks.  I was not aware of chroot.  Initially, I would like to deploy the web applications on Windows server.  In the future, platform neutral is better.  Java Security Manager policy looks the appropriate way for me to go that way!

Answer (score 0):

Hi it seems to be that you want restrict permission excluding all others folders.
you might want to use NIO.2 to update your permission by CHMOD, in older version of java
we do it by native code of your own.
Here is the link for NIO2.

[NIO2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/io/example/)